# Marketing Cloud - acquiring an access token

Tags: marketing-cloud, oauth2

Here is my request for authorization token in Postman:

`https://mc8fqc9ydvcn66zzz-zzzzkl4f0.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token/?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=yoxt7vzzzzzzzp5qe5zjr0ue&client_secret=nGgULjzzzzzzzzkYzAH9Bbvl&scope=email_read email_write email_send&account_id=6zzzzz2`

Here is response:

```js
{
    "error": "unsupported_grant_type",
    "error_description": "Use \"authorization_code\" or \"refresh_token\" or \"client_credentials\" or \"urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer\" as the grant_type.",
    "error_uri": "https://developer.salesforce.com/docs"
}
```

Domain and client credentials are from setup/installed packages in SFMC console. Seems like it should work.  I've tried all the numerous and confusing and contradictory documentation examples on the subject that Salesforce provides but to no avail.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

The [token request payload](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm) needs to be in a body of a POST whereas you're sending it as query parameters. Correct format:

```
Host: https://YOUR_SUBDOMAIN.auth.marketingcloudapis.com
POST /v2/token
Content-Type: application/json

{
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"client_id": "...",
"client_secret": "...",
"scope": "email_read"
}
```

Comment: This is what Postman  generates.  First time I ever used Postman.  Can you tell me how to set it up to send as body?  Thanks

Comment: @tomh Check SO for help on Postman, here's [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39008071/send-post-data-via-raw-json-with-postman)

Comment: Ok, I will.  I used SOAP UI to test. my post looks like this.                                                                                                                    
Host: https:https://myDomain.auth.marketingcloudapis.com
POST /v2/token
Content-Type: application/json
{
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"client_id":...",
"client_secret": "....",
"scope": "email_read"
}                                                                                                                                        Response:596 Service Not Found

Comment: 596 response code translates to `Invalid preflight CORS request: Missing Origin header or Request's Http Method is not OPTIONS`. For help with Soap UI, please post a question on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, my problem was having multiple Rest API "packages" created.  The one I was using was an old "legacy" API and the client credentials were not working.  Used the latest package credentials and was able to get an authorization token.